# MonoDevelop - Wildcards in csproj file

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xamarin.android

I've hooked up wildcards in some of my *.csproj files in Windows as the link describes [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/06/06/wildcard-content-using-msbuild.aspx).  Which is working great for us in Visual Studio on Windows.  Basically it provides a way to add all files of a type in a folder in your project.  That way our designers/animators can just drop in the files and commit.

Now I need this to work in MonoDevelop on the Mac.

Originally I tried duplicating what worked in Visual Studio, but that didn't work at all.  I'm guessing because it is MSBuild doing the work, which doesn't exist on the Mac.

So now, I'm trying to do similar in MonoDevelop on OS X, so I'm trying something like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="../../../Assets/images/iPhone/*.png">
      <Link>Content/*.png</Link>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

However, I get:

```
File '/MyPath/Assets/images/iPhone/*.png' is missing
```

Is there a way to make this work in MonoDevelop?  This would certainly speed up my process of adding images individually.  I need the links to work also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MonoDevelop does not support wildcards in project files. In general, if you enable the experimental xbuild support option, such constructs should *build* correctly for certain project types, even though they won't load correctly into the solution tree (not sure about wildcards in Link metadata). However, MonoTouch and MonoMac don't support xbuild yet, so this probably doesn't help you.

If this is important to you, please file an enhancement bug in the MonoDevelop [bug tracker](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com).

Comment: Is there anything I can do to make this easier?  My issue is I have to change *.mp3, *.xnb files to build `Content` to massive amounts of files that appear with source control when I checkout.  PNGs are set to `Content` by default, is there a setting where I could do this for xnb and mp3?  To complicate things, these files are also linked-in and not present in the folder.

Comment: @Jonathan.Peppers since it's all XML files you could create a script (or a small C# tool) that would synchronize the files you want (e.g. *.mp3) into all the entries you require from the .csproj (and then share it with everyone ;-)

Comment: @poupou, I think that is what I'll have to do in this case.  It would be nice for MonoDevelop to have more of these MSBuild features